# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'

Tags: android, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Emu_Application\android\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > 'org.gradle.api.file.DirectoryProperty org.gradle.api.file.ProjectLayout.directoryProperty(org.gradle.api.provider.Provider)'

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         8.3s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn02U.png)

Comment: I'm getting the same error, did you ever find a solution?